# Why does ActivateObject function return E_POINTER?

Tags: c++, windows, multiplexing

i'm trying to work with windows media fundation, get hang of it. I was following steps from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--1-pass-windows-media-encoding#create-the-asf-file-sink), and at some point i got stuck.

Let me describe my problem.

I am calling  `ActivateObject` function from object `IMFActivate`.
This function call is presented in tutorial, I guess, in proper way, so I just copy-pasted it and didn't put a lot of thought on it.

After I completed all steps from tutorial (and wrapped it in class myself(!!)), I tried to run it, and `HRESULT` from that function call is `E_POINTER` which means that invalid pointer was passed.

I won't copy-paste my whole code, i'll narrow it down to objects used, and call itself.
Here is how function call looks like:

```
HRESULT MediaMultiplexer::AddTransformOutputNodes(
    IMFTopology* pTopology,
    IMFActivate* pSinkActivate,
    IMFMediaType* pSourceType,
    IMFTopologyNode** ppNode
    )
{
    if (!pTopology || !pSinkActivate || !pSourceType)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    IMFTopologyNode* pEncNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pOutputNode = NULL;
    IMFASFContentInfo* pContentInfo = NULL;
    IMFASFProfile* pProfile = NULL;
    IMFASFStreamConfig* pStream = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pMediaType = NULL;
    IPropertyStore* pProps = NULL;
    IMFActivate* pEncoderActivate = NULL;
    IMFMediaSink* pSink = NULL;

    GUID guidMT = GUID_NULL;
    GUID guidMajor = GUID_NULL;

    DWORD cStreams = 0;
    WORD wStreamNumber = 0;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = pSourceType->GetMajorType(&guidMajor);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Create the node.
    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE, &pEncNode);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    //Activate the sink
    hr = pSinkActivate->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFMediaSink), (void**)&pSink);       //THIS CALL!!!!!
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
    //find the media type in the sink
    //Get content info from the sink
    hr = pSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFASFContentInfo), (void**)&pContentInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
```

And here is how i prepare IMFActivate used to call that function:

```
bool MediaMultiplexer::setFileName(std::string _fileName)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = MFCreateASFMediaSinkActivate(std::wstring(_fileName.begin(), _fileName.end()).c_str(), m_globalContentInfo, &m_globalActivate);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed creating ASF media sink activate", hr);
        return false;
    }
    m_globalActivate->AddRef();
    return true;
}
```

I just started working with MediaFundation so I don't know how important that is, so I'll show how i prepare contentInfo aswell, which is used to create IMFActivate.

```
    HRESULT hr;
    
    hr = MFCreateASFContentInfo(&m_globalContentInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed to create global content info", hr);
        return false;
    }
    PROPVARIANT var;
    var.vt = VT_BOOL;
    var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;

    hr = m_globalContentInfo->GetEncodingConfigurationPropertyStore(0, &m_globalStore);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed getting global store configuration", hr);
        return false;
    }

    hr = m_globalStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_ASFMEDIASINK_AUTOADJUST_BITRATE, var);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed setting value for bitrat adjust", hr);
        return false;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me, and thus, in future, anyone with similar issue will find his answer here :).
And i'm sorry for any sort of english related mistakes, i'm still just learning this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am stupid :)

I found mistake in my code.

While setting `m_globalContentInfo` i forgot to set profile.
In code it should be something like that:

```
//... 
    hr = m_globalStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_ASFMEDIASINK_AUTOADJUST_BITRATE, var);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed setting value for bitrat adjust", hr);
        return false;
    }



// I missed that part ealier

    hr = m_globalContentInfo->SetProfile(m_profile);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printError("Failed setting global profile");
        return false;
    }
```